# unique word abbreviation alternate solutions?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Help! Numerous solutions solved it in HashMap, it is more efficient than ArrayList, however for simplicity of code and as a beginner coder:

1. I was wondering if it can be solved in ArrayList: abbreviate all elements first and the given word, then compare if abbreviated given word matches any of the elements in the array. Please check the code that begins with "why not..." and the function"isUnique2". It keeps giving error, someone please tell me how it can be fixed.
2. My second idea was: to compare first && last element && length. Wouldn't this be much simpler? If not, please tell me why it is wrong.

   ```
   //<first letter><number><last letter> check if a word is unique
   //Given dictionary = [ "deer", "door", "cake", "card" ] ，isUnique("dear") -> false， isUnique("cart") -> true， isUnique("cane") -> false， isUnique("make") -> true

   public class UniqueWordAbbr {

   Map<String, String> map= new HashMap<String, String>();

   public static void main(String[] args){
       String[] dictionary  = { "deer", "door", "cake", "card" };
       UniqueWordAbbr uwa = new UniqueWordAbbr(dictionary);
       System.out.println(uwa.isUnique2 (dictionary,"cane"));
       System.out.println(uwa.isUnique("word"));
   }
   //why not create array to check if elements match???
   public boolean isUnique2(String[] dictionary, String word) {
       String abbr_w = abbreviate(word);
       List abbr_dictionary = new ArrayList(); 

       for(int i = 0; i<dictionary.length; i++){
           String n_w = abbreviate(dictionary[i]);
           abbr_dictionary.add(n_w);
       }
       for (Object copy : abbr_dictionary) {
           if (abbr_w.equals(copy))
                return false;
            else return true;
       }
       return false;
   }
   //1. abbreviate 
   private String abbreviate(String str){
       return str.charAt(0)+ Integer.toString(str.length()-2) + str.charAt(str.length()-1);
   }   
   //2. establish the map, convert array into map
   public UniqueWordAbbr(String[] dictionary){
         for(int i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i++){
           String abbr = abbreviate(dictionary[i]);
           //always check if map does NOT contain first!
           if (!map.containsKey(abbr)){
               map.put(abbr, dictionary[i]);
           }else{
               map.put(abbr, "");
           }   
       }
   }
   // check if word is unique
   public boolean isUnique(String word) {
       String abbr_w = abbreviate(word);
       //为啥不直接 查询 map.containsKey(abbr_w)?
           if (map.containsKey(abbr_w)) {
               //why also need to compare the value? 
               if (map.get(abbr_w).equals(word)){
                   return true;
               }else {
                   return false;
               }
           }
       return true;
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: you want to check if that element actually exists?

Comment: thank you for asking, my thought process was to abbreviate the entire dictionary (in ArrayList), and compare the abbreviated given word, see if the  given word exist in the ArrayList. Is that clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding your first question**: The idea might be considered ok (but see my performance comments below), but you seem to be inconsistent with when you want to abbreviate the dictionary items: you try to do it in the constructor, and then again in isUnique2() you do: `String n_w = abbreviate(dictionary[i]);`

**Regarding your second question**: I know that you already know the answer. :-)
Why do I know this? In the constructor `UniqueWordAbbr()` you already check for collisions of your abreviations: `if (!map.containsKey(abbr))`. So you know already, that collisions happen and have to be accounted for. The first line of defense against collisions is good hashing (=a good abbreviation method) – i.e. a method that makes collisions extremely unlikely. Your idea expressed in `abbreviate()` is not good at generating unique hashes. So your program will have to revert often to next lines of defenses that you will have to code (and so your program will slow down executing this additional code...)

**From the performance point of view** I would advise you to consider that:
1. it is a waste of time to abbreviate a significant part of the dictionary again and again at every call to `isUnique2()`.
It is more reasonable to abbreviate the whole dictionary less often, but doing so in constructor disables future updates to the existing dictionary. Performance-wise it is usually best to abbreviate at every update. 
2. You also have to store unabbreviated and abbreviated forms together, which you now only do locally in `List abbr_dictionary` which exists temporarily in `isUnique2()`. So you loose it quickly...

3. You are searching your dictionary using linear search. This is inefficient as the complexity of this search is O(n). But using e.g. binary search would require to keep the dictionary hashes (your 'abbreviations') ordered after every update.

Comment: Now I understand more the reason why store the unabbreviated and abbreviated forms together, instead of abbreviating the whole dictionary first. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to know I could help. You may consider accepting my above answer. :-)